# strange numpy fft performance

Tags: python, numpy, fft

During testing I have noticed something strange.

I’m FFT’ing a lot of vectors, and from time to time the numpy FFT function seemed to crash.

I briefly debugged this, and found that some vector lengths triggered the behavior.

By incident, I kept  a script running, and to my surprise, it was not crashed, it simply took a little longer.

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on, and how to counter act this.  I have seen this with many different FFT sizes, the below is an example only.

```
import numpy as np    
import time

a = np.zeros(166400)
start = time.time()
audio_fft = np.fft.fft(a,len(a))                          
print "it took %fs"%(time.time() -start)

a = np.zeros(165039)
start = time.time()
audio_fft = np.fft.fft(a,len(a))                          
print "it took %fs"%(time.time() -start)

a = np.zeros(165038)
start = time.time()
audio_fft = np.fft.fft(a,len(a))                          
print "it took %fs"%(time.time() -start)

a = np.zeros(165036)
start = time.time()
audio_fft = np.fft.fft(a,len(a))                          
print "it took %fs"%(time.time() -start)

a = np.zeros(165035)
start = time.time()
audio_fft = np.fft.fft(a,len(a))                          
print "it took %fs"%(time.time() -start)

a = np.zeros(165034)
start = time.time()
audio_fft = np.fft.fft(a,len(a))                          
print "it took %fs"%(time.time() -start)

a = np.zeros(165037)
start = time.time()
audio_fft = np.fft.fft(a,len(a))                          
print "it took %fs"%(time.time() -start)

print "done"
```

This outputs :

```
c:\Users\sol_sf\Desktop\math>fftTest.py
it took 0.029000s
it took 0.101000s
it took 0.176000s
it took 0.220000s
it took 0.671000s
it took 0.065000s
it took 369.132000s
done

c:\Users\sol_sf\Desktop\math>
```

Comment: There are a number of different algorithms used depending on the factorisation of len(a).  As you know, powers of 2 are fastest so if you can pad that is the best route.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Cooley.E2.80.93Tukey_algorithm has some more information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Divide-and-conquer FFT algorithms, such as [Cooley-Tukey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm), work much better the more factors the input length has. Powers of 2 work especially well, whereas primes (like 165037) require alternate, slower implementations. If you can pad your input to a power-of-2 length, you may be able to drastically speed up slow FFTs.

Comment: I'm aware that powers of 2 are great for FFts, and maybe I can understand that primes are slow as well, but e.g 480057, is slow as well - and its not a prime?

Comment: I will accept your answer, as it's kind of stupid making an 165037 points FFT, and in the end, you are probably right. I will do some overlap and add and stick to powers of 2.

Comment: Although your explanation is spot on, I don't think that the statement "primes require alternate, slower implementations" is true. What the FFT does is divide a DFT of size `N = P*Q` into `P` DFTs of size `Q` plus `Q` modified DFTs of size `P`. This is recursively repeated until a prime sized DFT is found, which is then calculated directly. The implementation is probably the same, regardless of whether the size of the prime sized DFT eventually found is 2 (input is a power of two), 3, 5 or 165037.

Comment: @Cyrex `480057 = 3 * 165037`, if you read my previous comment you'll understand why it performs worse than `165037` despite not being a prime.

Answer (score 2):

I think that power 2 padding of array some times has several disadvantages:

1. If you cut array to power 2 length it will produce a big loses of the data  for big arrays
2. If you pad array with zeros it will produce so called "edge effect"

I have found in this [topic](http://numpy-discussion.10968.n7.nabble.com/Numpty-FFT-FFT-slow-with-certain-samples-td40953.html) that fft performance depends on the array size prime factorization. If the array length is prime number it lead to long calculation time. So I propose following code that decreases array length looking for best it factorization.

```
from sympy.ntheory import factorint

FACTOR_LIMIT = 100

def bestFFTlength(n):
    while max(factorint(n)) >= FACTOR_LIMIT:
        n -= 1
    return n

a = np.zeros(166400)
audio_fft = np.fft.fft(a,bestFFTlength(len(a)))
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to solve this - that isn't mentioned in the other answers - is to use [scipy.fftpack.next_fast_len](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.next_fast_len.html) to pad the array. Given a target length, it gives you the next length > target that is a composite of 2,  3 and 5.

As the other answers have pointed out, FFT performs the worst when the array's length is a prime number. Its efficiency increases as the number of prime factors increase (2, 3, 5, etc.).