# Optimizing Fourier transformed signal length

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I recently stumbled on an interessting problem, when computing the fourier transform of a signal with [`np.fft.fft`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft). The reproduced problem is:

```
%timeit np.fft.fft(np.random.rand(59601))    
1 loops, best of 3: 1.34 s per loop
```

I found that the amount of time is unexpectedly long. For instance lets look at some other fft's, but with a slightly longer/shorter signal:

```
%timeit np.fft.fft(np.random.rand(59600))
100 loops, best of 3: 6.18 ms per loop

%timeit np.fft.fft(np.random.rand(59602))
10 loops, best of 3: 61.3 ms per loop

%timeit np.fft.fft(np.random.rand(59603))
10 loops, best of 3: 113 ms per loop

%timeit np.fft.fft(np.random.rand(59604))
1 loops, best of 3: 182 ms per loop

%timeit np.fft.fft(np.random.rand(59605))
100 loops, best of 3: 6.53 ms per loop

%timeit np.fft.fft(np.random.rand(59606))
1 loops, best of 3: 2.17 s per loop

%timeit np.fft.fft(np.random.rand(59607))
100 loops, best of 3: 8.14 ms per loop
```

We can observe that the times are now in miliseconds, except for `np.random.rand(59606)`, which lasts 2.17 s.

Note, the numpy documentation states:

> FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) refers to a way the discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) can be calculated efficiently, by using symmetries in the calculated terms. The symmetry is highest when n is a power of 2, and the transform is therefore most efficient for these sizes.

However these vectors do not have the length of a power of 2. Could someone explain how to avoid/predict cases, when computation times are considerably higher?

Comment: 59601 is 3*19867, and 19867 is prime.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161033/strange-numpy-fft-performance

Comment: Also, 59606 is 2*29803, and 29803 is prime.  For a really slow case, try 59611, which is prime.

Comment: Yes, this is it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As some comments have pointed, the prime factor decomposition allows you to predict the time to calculate the FFT. The following graphs show your results. Remark the logarithmic scale!
[image: FFT timings]

This image is generated with the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def prime_factors(n):
    """Returns all the prime factors of a positive integer"""
    #from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287/largest-prime-factor-of-a-number/412942#412942
    factors = []
    d = 2
    while n > 1:
        while n % d == 0:
            factors.append(d)
            n /= d
        d = d + 1

    return factors


times = []
decomp = []
for i in range(59600, 59613):
    print(i)
    t= %timeit -o np.fft.fft(np.random.rand(i))
    times.append(t.best)
    decomp.append(max(prime_factors(i)))

plt.loglog(decomp, times, 'o')
plt.ylabel("best time")
plt.xlabel("largest prime in prime factor decomposition")
plt.title("FFT timings")
```